# How to increase city distance limit to greater than 4?

Tags: civilization-5, mods

In Civ 5 you can't build two cities near 4 tiles, is it possible to increase this limit to 8?

E.g. You can't build two cities within 8 or less tiles between.

I feel in late game the continent map is so crowded with sooooo many cities, I think making cities more sparse would be more fun for me. After city area expansion max out, there would still be a gap between cities where you can pass through to hit players you don't like.

Comment: I don't think this is possible from within the game settings. Someone might come up with an answer for you that involves a mod, or digging around ini files.

Comment: @shanodin That's what I tought. Any mods can do that?

Comment: I know that it is a single setting in some XML, I just completely forgot where and what though. You can definitely change it.

Comment: Keep in mind that maximum city expansion range is 5 tiles, not 3. So technically you'll need a minimum range of 11. Though in practice it usually takes cities a long while before they get to 5 tiles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MIN_CITY_RANGE` in `GlobalDefines.xml`

```
...\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines.xml
...\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines.xml
...\steamapps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion2\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines.xml
```

Comment: GlobalDefines.xml is often at C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization V\Assets\Gameplay\XML on windows

Comment: and `Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines. xml` for G&K 

and `Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\sid meier's civilization v\assets\DLC\Expansion2\Gameplay\XML\GlobalDefines. xml` for BNW respectively

for convenience

Comment: do you know how to define MAX_CITY_RANGE?